# avahi-browse only find localhost, but no other network devices

Tags: avahi

When running `avahi-browse -arvp` I only get results back from my own laptop, but nothing else (I ran `avahi-browse -arvp` on my Pi and I get all the network devices)

So I copied the `/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf` from my Pi to my laptop, restarted the avahi-daemon, but still only results from my own laptop...

I removed and reinstalled `avahi`, but still only results from my own laptop... what am i missing here?

This used to work, but then for some reason, it stopped showing network connected devices and honesty I have no idea where to start looking to fix this.

Comment: Do you have any kind of firewall running that might be interfering with multicast traffic?

Comment: no firewall, it worked before and for some reason (i don't know why) it stopped working (doesn't find any network device)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my RPi(Ubuntu).
The cause of it is to collision of .local domain in my local network.
Avahi detects that .local is used, then it stops itself.

So you should change `/etc/default/avahi-daemon` file like:

```
# AVAHI_DAEMON_DETECT_LOCAL=1
AVAHI_DAEMON_DETECT_LOCAL=0
```

Answer (score 0):

On Rocky Linux 9 (RHEL, CentOS) avahi-browse didn't show anything for me because by default mdns is not allowed by firewall for the zone "public" which is assigned to any wireless connection.
I had to reassign my wi-fi to firewall zone "home" by running:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=home --change-interface=wlp8s0f3u4
```

where "wlp8s0f3u4" is my wi-fi interface name. You can get it from

```
ip a
```

It should have a name starting with "wl"